# How to filter cached requests in chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, caching, google-chrome-devtools

### Background

**Chrome devtools "Network" tab** has the option to filter requests based on string-match of the URL and some predefined content type filters (CSS/JS/...). If you set a filter, the bottom bar of the network tab, contains extra information related only to the matching filter.

### Question

**Is it possible to filter requests if they were served (or not) by browser cache?**

### Usecase

If someone has an alternate approach to do this:

I would like to measure the "real" request-count/transferred-size of my HTML-UI. The bottom of the network tab already contains the transferred-size properly, however the request-count contains the cached requests also.

I could use wireshark/tcpdump however, the HTML-UI could request resources from other domains, maybe I could write a complicated filter, however this seems a normal use-case.

Answer (score 21):

You can use a filter of `larger-than:1` to hide all requests that returned less than 1 byte.  When I tested this, requests served from the cache have *(from cache)* in the size column and are excluded by this filter.  Negating it showed only cache cached requests.

Granted, this will also exclude/include 0B responses from the server. If that's a concern, you might be able to add mimetype or status code filters to achieve your aims, depending on the exact responses.

Comment: How do I show only those requests which were cached ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 I thought that was a silly question until I went to confirm it. It took me an inordinate amount of time to verify that you'd use `-larger-than:1` (note the minus sign)

Comment: But that will also include all 0b responses unless you have some other way to filter them out

Answer (score 20):

You can filter requests served from either the browser disk or memory caches using the `is:from-cache` query. This can be negated using the query `-is:from-cache`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this obviously very well hidden secret in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for posting the query, it really helped.

Comment: Cool. Learnt something useful for the day :)

Answer (score 0):

For one of your filters use `-status-code:304`. This will hide things loaded from cache. Then the request count and transferred amount will show the number of filtered out of the total for the page. If you say want to check only the cached items, then remove the negation from the filter.

[image: Filtering by status code]

Comment: browser cache is something different. 304 is a legit request/response to the server, that the etag is the same as you've had it before. the browser-cached requests appear as status-code:200

Comment: Then you can't currently filter it out specifically. Why exactly do you need to filter that out? I don't see in any case where it is useful.

Comment: I want to see actual requests made across the wire by the browser. I can think of a lot of cases wherein that would matter.

Comment: If you can think of "a lot of cases" then please provide examples so they can be looked into. If you really need "actual requests as they are made on the wire" then look into Wireshark or another packet inspection tool.

Comment: Someone else's server - can't download extra tools. Debugging web app behavior - limiting requests to those actually being handled by the server. Debugging unexpected throughput testing results - comparing requests sent from a real browser to those sent by a load tester that doesn't cache.  Two of those are very large categories that encompass an enormous variety of real-world tasks.

Comment: @Garbee - Does John's comment answer you question ? Does it make sense ?